# SQL Server error: Invalid column name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql

when some link "Make Default" is clicked the following SP is executed. 
What I want is that when the link "Make Default " is clicked then
only the "IsDefault" record corresponding to the particular "UserAddressID"
 is set to 1 and ALL the rest of records to be set to 0 in the teable's column

giving me the following error:-

> Invalid column name 'UserAddressID'

When the column exists! Whats wrong with my SP??

Comment: if(UserAddressID!=@UserAddressID)   -- what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Pavan..a user can add many address but only ONE address can be default..I need to set "IsDefault" col's value in the table to 1 when the user click's "Make DEfault " link on my aspx page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if(UserAddressID!=@UserAddressID)
```

The column `UserAddressID` does not exist outside the scope of the SQL statement.

In fact you don't need the if statement at all. The condition you are checking for is already included in the SQL.

You can also combine both queries into a single update:

```
UPDATE SC.UserAddressDetails
SET IsDefault = (CASE WHEN UserAddressID=@UserAddressID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: so how do I set the rest of the records to 0 in the IsDefault column if not this way ?

Comment: yeah need to update for one user only..but UserAddressID is taking care of that..I thot so :/ UserAddressID is unique for every user

Comment: Plz help me out with this..I am confused

Comment: Use `SET IsDefault=0` instead of `SET IsDefault=1` in your second query.

Comment: ok my updated SP has now set ALL the records under IsDefault col to 1!

Answer (score 1):

You can update the IsDefault value to 1 using -

```
UPDATE SC.UserAddressDetails SET IsDefault=1 WHERE UserAddressID=@UserAddressID
```

In your table structure you can set the default value for ISDefault as 0. In which case you wont need to update all the records again using

```
ALTER TABLE SC.UserAddressDetails ADD CONSTRAINT default_isdefault DEFAULT 0 FOR IsDefault
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a schema problem which is why your stored procs are getting confusing.  Make a column called DefaultUserAddressID in your Users table, .  Then there can only be one.  Making an IsDefault column on the Addresses table isn't very good design since it uses more data to achieve the same thing, is error prone and requires you to make all sorts of other checks in all stored procs that update address information.

Simple is better.